# Is Spider-man's suit in Infinity War nanotech?

Tags: character, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-infinity-war, spider-man-homecoming

In *Avengers: Infinity War*, Spider-Man gets a new suit from Iron Man during their way up to space. The suit was also seen in the ending of *Spider-Man: Homecoming*.

Iron Man used a nano tech suit in the movie. Is the suit given to Spider-Man also nano tech? Is there any reference to this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not *explicity* stated but the indications are that it is.

We see the suit arrive (by jetpack) and as it deploys on Spider-man it does so by *flowing* across his body as does the Iron Man armour for Stark.

[image]

In addition, the Spider-armour deploys **legs**, effectively from nowhere (certainly there is no space on Spider-Man's back for them to be stored) a further indication that the armor is nano-tech.

[image]